# how to group several functions to collapse in C

Tags: c, function, ide, code-folding

i want to group a few functions (like methods in java packages) to clear out the useless things on the screen while i'm coding, so i tried this in basic C :

```
{ //these are the functions i want to collapse
    void test1()
    {
    }

    void test2()
    {
    }

    void test3()
    {
    }
}
```

and it did not worked, how can i do it?

Comment: In C you cannot nest functions. Also MSVC gives *error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)*

Comment: I don't think you can group top-level function definitions in a block. Blocks can only be used inside functions.

Comment: Maybe you should just split your project into multiple source files. Put all these functions in one file, and then you can work on a different file.

Comment: I think it's a question about IDE/editor. Which one are you using?

Comment: @NicolasCaous: Why do you expect two different languages provide the same features/semantics?

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are talking about is **Code Folding** or **Code Collapsing**, and it is an IDE feature only, not specifically a language feature.

Some IDE's will allow you to collapse methods automatically without any code changes. Visual Studio for .NET will let you add `#region` and `#endregion` to make a collapsible section of code (such as a group of Utility functions).

Check your IDE's documentation to see if it supports Code Folding.

More information can be found here:

[Wikipedia: Code Folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_folding)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `#pragma region` and `#pragma endregion` as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6xkz944.aspx). It works in Visual Studio and might work in other IDEs.

Comment: The link does not show those functions contained in a `{`block`}`

Comment: The question's a bit vague, but I think that OP simply wants to visually hide/collapse some code.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't use an IDE but perhaps you could correct OP's example?

Comment: @WeatherVane What do you think "clear out the useless things on the screen while I'm coding" means, if not about code folding in the editor/IDE?

Comment: @Barmar plainly from your earlier comments you did not catch it either.

Comment: @WeatherVane I certainly did, I just didn't know that IDEs have ways of collapsing without reference to code blocks.

Comment: @Barmar that's a QED